# Append a query string to a pre-constructed URI (C#, Unity3D)

Tags: c#, http, plugins, unity-game-engine, uri

Using Unity3D and the BestHttp plugin, is there a better way to append a query string to a Request's URI then reconstructing an HTTP request like I have shown below? Mind you Unity is running on sub-set of mono 3.5.

```
var str = _request.Uri.OriginalString;

    str += "&page_number=0";

    _request = new HTTPRequest(new Uri(str));
```

Edit**

Thank you,

I don't think I was clear enough though. The question is less about how to create the string and more about how to append that page number to the already constructed / configured request without having to reconstruct a full HTTP request and set all of its callbacks and other values. The set Accessor for the httpRequest's URI is inaccessible.

Comment: updated my answer for more explanation about why the Uri property read-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For your edit**:
The Uri property is read-only because it would be too easy to shout yourself in the foot by exposing cookies, form data and other potentially sensitive information to a 3rd party server.
To avoid this, the plugin will not let you reuse the same request for a different Uri.

I think the best you can do is using the UriBuilder class:

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(req.CurrentUri);
builder.Query += "page_number=0";
Debug.Log(builder.Uri);
```

It will add the first "?" char, but for current implementation in Unity, if you use the += operator multiple times, it will add multiple "?" chars:

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(req.CurrentUri);
builder.Query += "page_number=0";
builder.Query += "&page_number=2";
builder.Query += "&page_number=4";

Debug.Log(builder.Uri);
```

This will produce an output like this:

> http://httpbin.org/get???page_number=0&page_number=2&page_number=4

So, you can struggle with these limitations, or you can stick with your original string approach.

Answer (score 1):

i find useful the Flurl library https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl that's just a simple collection of Extensions that help you build URL starting from a string

as example, in your scenario, it would be something like

```
var str = _request.Uri.OriginalString.SetQueryParams("page_number", "0");
```

it has a Fluent API so it's really easy to build url
on the homepage of that project there is an example that speak for itself

```
var result = await "https://api.mysite.com"
.AppendPathSegment("person")
.SetQueryParams(new { api_key = "xyz" })
.WithOAuthBearerToken("my_oauth_token")
.PostJsonAsync(new { first_name = firstName, last_name = lastName })
.ReceiveJson<T>();
```

the example does much more that what you need, because it already post something and read the response, so you can just use extensions to build the path and querystring